# How to convert Moment to another moment depending on timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I really bad in JS and I'm struggling with moment.js

My wish is: get a date from a div (UTC) and convert this date depending on the timezone of the user.

So if the UTC date is 30/03/2017 6:34:22 AM
Someone in New York sees 30/03/2017 2:34:22 AM
Someone in Perth sees 30/03/2017 2:34:22 PM

I did something similar in C# with TimeZoneInfo and IsDaylightSavingTime but I don't know how to do this in JS.

Below my code:

```
// <div id="utc-time">30/03/2017 6:34:22 AM</div>

var dt = document.getElementById("utc-time").innerHTML;  
var m = moment(dt, "DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss a");
var tz = moment.tz.guess();
var user = moment.tz(dt, "DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss a", tz);
var mString = m.toString();

// Console.log
// -----------
dt = 30/03/2017 6:34:22 AM
m = 1490826862000
user = Thu Mar 30 2017 06:34:22 GMT+0800
mString = Wed Mar 29 2017 22:34:22 GMT+0000
```

It looks like the moment created is not UTC but keep the local timezone. A hint would be nice :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use moment [`local()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) to convert moment object to user local time, while you can use [`tz()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) to convert time between zones.

Use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) to parse date as UTC. Use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to show values of moment objects.

If you just need to support UTC and user local time, you don't need moment-timezone.

Here a working sample:

```js
var dt = document.getElementById("utc-time").innerHTML;  
var m = moment.utc(dt, "DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss A"); // parse input as UTC
console.log(m.clone().local().format("DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss A")); // local time
var tz = 'America/New_York'; // example value, you can use moment.tz.guess()
console.log(m.clone().tz(tz).format("DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss A")); // 30-03-2017 2:34:22 AM
tz = 'Australia/Perth';
console.log(m.clone().tz(tz).format("DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss A")); // 30-03-2017 2:34:22 PM
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.7/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>

<div id="utc-time">30/03/2017 6:34:22 AM</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to convert date to another timezone in moment js ,use `utcOffset` and provide the offset just like below

```
moment(new Date()).utc().utcOffset("+05:30").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: moment(...).utc() seems to be also equivalent to moment.parseZone(...)