# How to convert date to different timezone

Tags: timezone, momentjs

I have a date in string format as:

```
var x = '2017-07-11 12:00';
var timeZone = 'America/New_York'
```

Now how can I format date according to timeZone? What I am expecting is:

```
var y = someMagicalFunction(x,timeZone)
// y = '2017-07-10 14:30'
```

Also reverse of it:

```
var x = reverseOfMagicalFunction(y, 'Asia/Kolkata');
// x = '2017-07-11 12:00';
```

I have used `moment.tz` to get results when x was of type `Date`.

```
var x1 = x.toISOString();
var y = moment.utc(x).tz(timezone).format('YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss');
```

but was not able to get ReverseMagicalFucntion in that case. Any help?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  You say your x input is in `America/New_York`, but you don't say what `someMagicalFunction` is doing.  All I can see is that you're getting `y` output that is 21.5 hours earlier - which doesn't make sense for *any* time zone...  (Also, `hh` in your output is for 12-hour clock, you probably want `HH` unless you also ask for the am/pm indicator).

Comment: I agree with Matt Johnson, your question is a bit unclear, are you searching how to convert moment objects between timezones? Probably [`tz()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) docs could help you and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43113350/4131048) question could point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using momentjs, you can try something like ([Check Here](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)):

```
moment(date).tz('Europe/Berlin').format(format);
```