# Convert time from other timezone to local timezone using moment/moment-timezone

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a tradingHours object

```
tradingHours = [
 {
  dayCode: "Monday",
  TimeZone: "Australia/Sydney",
  OpenHour: "08:30:00",
  CloseHour: "17:00:00"
 }
]
```

What I want to do is to display the local openTime/closeTime based on the local time zone.

For example, my local timezone will be "Australia/Perth", the different is three hours, then the openTime is "05:30", and the closeTime is "14:00".

I went through couple of solutions I found in other post, but none of them is what I needed.

I could calculate the different minutes(-180), then do some coding to calculated the corresponding time.

However, I believe there must be a better way to achieve it.

Appreciate for any help.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43113350/4131048), I think you can simply use moment-timezone's [`tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) function.

Comment: @VincenzoC Thanks for the help, I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment-timezone's .tz function as following:

```js
var tradingHours = [
 {
  dayCode: "Monday",
  TimeZone: "Australia/Sydney",
  OpenHour: "08:30:00",
  CloseHour: "17:00:00"
 }
]

var a = moment.tz(tradingHours[0].OpenHour, 'HH:mm:ss', tradingHours[0].TimeZone)

console.log(a.tz('Australia/Perth').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ'));
// or
console.log(a.local().format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```