# Timezone conversion returning the same tz I pass in

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I am trying to convert UTC datetime to a different timezone using `moment.utc().tz('Asia/Kamchatka')` and the return value is also in UTC. What am I doing wrong? I have a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/satish_appasani/vnm1kdst/

Answer (score 0):

I think `moment.utc().tz('Asia/Kamchatka').format()` can do the trick for you.

Comment: I already had a format() in the fiddle I shared. It doesn't work.

Comment: I think this might solve your problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113350/how-to-convert-moment-to-another-moment-depending-on-timezone)