# How to convert any timezone to local timezone in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The below code converts the date to local timezone:

```
function convertDateToServerDate(incomingDate) {
 var serverOffset = new Date();
 serverOffset = serverOffset.getTimezoneOffset();
 var outgoingServerDate = new Date((incomingDate.getTime() + Math.abs(serverOffset * 60 * 1000)));
 return outgoingServerDate;
}
```

I have a date in the IST timezone. I'm also in the IST timezone the above function changes the time whereas it should just return it. I also tried converting to UTC then back to the local but the same result. How to get a local timezone and do nothing if the date is already in local time zone?

Comment: Have you heard of [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) before?

Comment: Yes. I have. But I thought If I can do this with vanilla javascript then why to use moment.

Comment: Moment.js itself recommends that you don't use moment.js anymore, they even have [a list of good alternatives](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) on their site

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with vanilla Javascript without a library, because the `Date` class only comprehends two timezones: GMT, and local. ([Source](https://maggiepint.com/2017/04/09/fixing-javascript-date-getting-started/)]

Libraries like momentjs and date-fns do not merely provide convenient functions, they very importantly also include [hard-coded datasets](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/tree/develop/data/unpacked) that specify current real-world facts about time zone adjustments, including things like the dates where DST switches. This is vital, because if you look at [the map of timezones](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/World_Time_Zones_Map.png/1920px-World_Time_Zones_Map.png), you'll see that the boundaries of the different zones are not straight lines. That's because they are determined by humans who made interesting compromises which are then enshrined in custom and law.

Many of those compromises are there so that people who share a jurisdiction can also share a clock. It would be enormously inconvenient for them otherwise, and many people would be adversely impacted every single day.

There is a proposal for a successor to `Date`, called [`Temporal`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/), that would remedy this.

Comment: It says, Don't use in production.

Comment: @eras'q I said it was a proposal, I did not say to use it. I included the link for two reasons: as proof of my assertion that current `Date` is inadequate, and because it explains the limitations better than I do. IIRC, one of the linked pages also has recipes for some workarounds, but I haven't read it in a while.

Comment: The INTL locale has this in native JS

Answer (score 1):

Best to use moment library.  https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

`moment().tz(String)`

`var a = moment.utc("2013-11-18 11:55").tz("Asia/Taipei");`

`var b = moment.utc("2013-11-18 11:55").tz("America/Toronto");`

`a.format(); // 2013-11-18T19:55:00+08:00`

`b.format(); // 2013-11-18T06:55:00-05:00`

`a.utc().format(); // 2013-11-18T11:55Z`

`b.utc().format(); // 2013-11-18T11:55Z`

Comment: Here you are specifying the time zones what if the time zones are unknown? And I want to convert the unknown time zone to a local time zone.

Comment: You can use moment local() to convert moment object to user local time, while you can use tz() to convert time between zones.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113350/how-to-convert-moment-to-another-moment-depending-on-timezone

Answer (score 1):

The server offset has to be set using INTL, hardcoded or come from the server

So something like this

```js
const serverOffset = -240; // this is static
function convertDateToServerDate(incomingDate) {
  const incomingOffset = incomingDate.getTimezoneOffset();
  if (serverOffset === incomingOffset) return incomingDate;
  console.log(serverOffset-incomingOffset,"difference")
  const outGoingDate = new Date(incomingDate.getTime())
  outGoingDate.setTime(incomingDate.getTime() + ((serverOffset-incomingOffset) * 60 * 1000));
  return outGoingDate;
}

console.log(convertDateToServerDate(new Date()))
```

Comment: Here, `serverOffset` is coming to be -330 which is my local offset. Then why do we have to hardcode it?

Comment: Would it work changing your first line with `d = new Date(); const serverOffset = d.getTimeZoneOffset()` ?

Comment: It's not working. `TypeError: d.getTimeZoneOffset is not a function` but why? `var serverOffset = new Date();
serverOffset = serverOffset.getTimezoneOffset();` is working. *Confused

Comment: No. The hardcoded thing works. I was talking about without the hardcoded part. `let d = new Date(); const serverOffset = d.getTimeZoneOffset()` throws error. `var serverOffset = new Date(); serverOffset = serverOffset.getTimezoneOffset();` does not.

Comment: I do not have d. But you have an uppercase `Z` in your getTimeZoneOffset